# Emacs is not recognizing files as latex and going into latex-mode?

Tags: emacs

I understand that the `tex-mode` command of Emacs is supposed to try to identify whether a file is TeX, LaTeX or some other TeX-variant when opening a .tex file, and switch automatically into the appropriate mode. But mine is not doing this despite my verifying that `tex-default-mode` is set to `latex-mode`. Regardless of what I have in my `document.tex` file, Emacs loads tex-mode and the status line says "TeX" instead of "LaTeX". If I run `latex-mode`, it goes into the right mode.

Is there anything I have to do in my `.emacs` in order to have this recognize properly?

Comment: In my case it was a problem with [AUCTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777189/what-is-the-difference-of-tex-mode-and-latex-mode-and-latex-mode-in-emacs).

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to write

```
% Emacs, this is -*-latex-*-
```

or similar at the top of your file (all that matters is the `-*-latex-*-` part), or at the bottom you could put

```
% Local Variables:
% mode: latex
% End:
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as this. Turned out that putting the document class right at the top of the file was enough to convince Tex mode that it was a latex file rather than a tex file i.e. my documents now start:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
```

rather than starting with the title.

Answer (score 2):

One good option is to use the `auto-mode-alist` feature and add the following to your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.latex$" . latex-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: But most people don't name their LaTeX files to end with `.latex` (almost everyone uses `.tex`), so this won't be too helpful. I guess you could change `.latex` in the answer to `.tex`, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you never use plain-TeX you can add this in your `emacs.d`:

```
(add-hook 'plain-TeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-mode)
```

Each time the plain-TeX mode is used, it is switched to LaTeX mode.

Be aware that it will be harder to go back to plain-TeX mode and it's an hackish solution.

Comment: I think you're mixing Emacs' built-in `tex-mode` and AUCTeX: the question is about the former, your answer is about the latter.